# how to solve Highcharts error #15?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hello friends I'm trying to draw the chart using javascript function the data comes into JSON array format like

```
[[1432116687000,5100],[1432116991000,5100],[1432117291000,5100],[1432117591000,5100],[1432117894000,5100],[1432118199000,5100],[1432118499000,5100],[1432118800000,5100],[1432119100000,5100],[1432119404000,5100],[1432119648000,5100],[1432119950000,5100],[1432120250000,5100],[1432120550000,5100],[1432120850000,5100],[1432121154000,5100],[1432121154000,5100]]
```

But I'm getting an error 
**Highcharts Error #15**
*Highcharts expects data to be sorted*

This happens when you are trying to create a line series or a stock chart where the data is not sorted in ascending X order. For performance reasons, Highcharts does not sort the data, instead it is required that the implementer pre-sorts the data.
please help me to fix it

```
function drawChart(data){

        console.log(data);
        var date = [];
        var ttc = [];
        var series = [];
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

            //date.push(data[i][0]);
            //console.log(date);
            //ttc.push(parseInt(data[i][1]));
            //console.log(ttc);
            series.push([data[i][0],parseInt(data[i][1])]);
        } 
        //console.log(data[i][1]);
         //var series = (series);

 $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Area Per TCC'
        },

         yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'TTC'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'TCC',
            data: series
         }]
    });
```

} ;

Comment: Why are two last points the same? `[1432121154000,5100],[1432121154000,5100]`

Comment: after testing in a JSFiddle,  it really seems that the only problem. apparently and X point in stock/line charts can't share value.

Comment: Even if the two last points are the same this does not generate the error you are describing. I'd still assume that your JSON data is simply not sorted ascending. This is your exact data example, and code: http://jsfiddle.net/ekdwgLdp/

Comment: Of course, the solution to an error stating "Highcharts expects data to be sorted" would be to sort the data. If your question is "How do I sort my data", then I would update your post to reflect that.

Comment: i'm giving data as a parameter to a function which contains the date and ttc.  I have sorted the date before parse into json array
at JS function gives error that data to be sorted 
if you know how to do it then please help me

Comment: So now your question is how to sort data? Referring to your case, I run this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vzmadwa0/1/ and seems to working fine, beside there is the same x multiple time. Are you able to recreate your demo as live?